# How to create trigger with 'not for replication' in merge replication of MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

What is the syntax to create trigger with 'not for replication' in merge replication in MSSQL? I explored for the syntax a lot but couldn't found any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create TRIGGER [dbo].[Update_Stock]
   ON  [dbo].[Orders]
   AFTER  INSERT
AS
BEGIN

---some code

END
```

now you need to alter trigger like below

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Update_Stock] 
   ON  [dbo].[Orders]
   AFTER  INSERT
NOT for Replication — ‘marked as not for replication’
```

**REFERENCES:**
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/repltalk/2010/02/22/all-about-not-for-replication/